# GCS - Cost migrating data to Archive Bucket

Tags: google-cloud-storage

I would like to know how much I would save by transferring 1 TB of data from a standard regional bucket to an Archive bucket located in the same region (and within the same project).

I understand that the cost can be split in **Data Storage**, **Network Usage** and **Operations Usage**.

For the **Data Storage**:

- The cost of storing 1 TB in a Standard bucket per month : 1024 * 0.020 $ = 20.48 $
- The cost of storing 1 TB in an Archive bucket per month : 1024 * 0.0012 $ = 1.2288 $

Which means that I would save 19.2512 $ per month.

For the **Network Usage**:

- I assume that this cost for the transfer will be 0 because the data will move from one region to the same.

For the **Operations Usage**:

- Retrieval cost from the Standard bucket : 0.004 $

  It should need less than 10000 Class B operations to gather all the files.
- Insertion cost in the Archive bucket : 0.50 $

  It should need around 1024 * 1024 / 128  = 8192 operations of Class A. (1 per directory, 1 per file, and for each file larger than 128MB 1 per additional 128MB.)

So in total, I would have to pay 0.504$ once to transfer all the files to the Archive bucket and the bucket will cost me 1.2288 $ instead of 20.48 $.

Is my calculation correct or did I miss something ?

Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/pricing#price-tables) on Cloud Storage Pricing your estimates seem to be correct. Moreover, the amount of data you would like to transfer is quite minimal so the charges would be low as well.

Keep in mind that Archive storage class implies that reads, early writes and deletions would be charged accordingly as shown [here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/pricing#operations-pricing), so if you pretend to access that data often or overwrite the files therein it might be better to stay with the Stadard storage class.

Lastly, there is also a pricing calculator to make this kind of estimates that could be found [here](https://cloud.google.com/products/calculator).

Comment: early write and DELETION!